# How to user a group by with lambda?

Tags: c#, lambda, group-by

I'm trying to use lambda to get data from a table/resultset and generate objects with lists of other objects inside 
I have a list of elements e.g.:

```
continent | country | state

europe    | france  | paris
europe    | france  | rouen
europe    | spain   | madrid
europe    | italy   | milan
america   | usa     | ohio
america   | usa     | kansas
america   | usa     | texas
america   | usa     | iowa
america   | mexico  | colima
america   | mexico  | tabasco
africa    | niger   | maradi
africa    | niger   | tahoua
africa    | niger   | niamey
```

And I need to group it by continent and country in order to generate a list of object which will have lists of objects... something like:

- europe

  - france

    - paris
    - rouen
  - spain

    - madrid
  - italy

    - milan
- america

  - usa

    - ohio
    - kansas
    - texas
    - iowa
  - mexico

    - colima
    - tabasco
- africa

  - niger

    - maradi
    - tahoua
    - niamey

What i have is like:

```
   DataTable.GroupBy(g => new
      {
         g.continent,
         g.country
      })
   .Select(s => s.First()).ToList().ForEach(n =>
      {
         _continentals.Add(new Continent 
         {
            name = n.continent,
            countries = new List<Country> 
            {
               new Country
               {
                  name = n.country,
                  states = new List<State> 
                  {
                     new State
                     {
                        name = n.state
                     }
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
```

But it is not working, and I don't know how to fix it 
(it isn't generating/grouping the elements in the correct order).

Comment: Why are you doing `.Select(s => s.First())`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to group by continent and then group each of those groups by country, rather than grouping once based on the pair of continent/country:

```
var query = DataTable.GroupBy(item => item.continent,
    (key, group) => new
    {
        Continent = key,
        Countries = group.GroupBy(item => item.country)
    });
```